# Enterprise grade file sharing

Tags: linux, web, share

Can anybody suggest any web based application ( enterprise grade) that will allow my internal users to share files with the outside world. Maybe something like yousendit, but I want to be able to host it in my network. It doesn't have to be opensource as long as it runs on a linux platform.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [AjaXplorer](http://www.ajaxplorer.info/wordpress/).  Dead bang simple for end users, nothing more than LAMP to run.

Answer (score 1):

[FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: +1, given the original question, ftp seems fine.

Comment: In this day and age, I'm suspect of anyone that recommends FTP, especially when targeted for use outside of a trusted LAN environment.

Comment: @ErikaA - It doesn't say that the file retreivers will be a set of trusted users. In fact, it specifically says "with the outside world" - so an insecure protocol, or even using anonymous authentication, would fit the question just fine.

Comment: FTP may or may not be a good answer depending on the specifics. I do think the answer could have provided a *little* bit more information, though.

Comment: @Andrew - IMHO FTP is *never* the answer. Either SCP or WebDAV/https would seem to be two much superior alternatives.

Comment: @ErikA I understand, and do not necessarily disagree. I was just explaining why I voted down on this answer.

Comment: @Andrew - fair enough.

Comment: Anything but FTP.

Comment: Accellion or Allardsoft File Transfer seems to be suited for that purpose.

Comment: How does this keep getting voted up?  Its not web-based, its not user friendly, and its mostly broken when used "with the outside world."

Answer (score 1):

One word: WebDAV (if you really want it to be web based, else you can try scp/sftp with private key and forced commands)

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at either Accellion or Allardsoft File Transfer, very broadly similar but vastly different pricing.

Both are VM's so they don't strictly fit your "Must run on Linux" criteria, but they do "just work" and are focussed on sending and receiving files.

One key thing as well, they are both "self service", no setting up FTP users or having pissed users calling because no-one was there in IT when they needed to send a 5gb file at the last minute on a Friday.

Comment: Allardsoft File Transfer is exactly what I want. Now, I have to look at Accellion.

Comment: We have Accellion.  It's good, and you do pay for that but if the data is important and (as with us) it stops you shipping CD's and DVD's around the country/world it can pay for itself.  I don't know how "enterprise" you need, but the Allardsoft solution struck me as very good, though I've not used it.  Put it this way, I spent a *lot* of time looking and couldn't find anything similar, nor could I "roll my own" for less money.

Comment: Curious if you guys still use these products? I constantly need to send out 10-35GB files to multiple large companies (with large pipes), so speed is a concern. We use to use DigiDelivery (now Aspera Faspex). It worked well, and the UDP client was blazing fast, but it's expensive!

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Quickr can do that. The bad news is: you either have to run Lotus Domino, or an IBM WebSphere/DB2 as a back-end datastore.

Answer (score 0):

The [Turnkey Linux File Server](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/fileserver) uses [eXtplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/). Works well.